# Primefaces 3.5 DataTable Single Selection does not work with ContextMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

I tried to make a `<p:dataTable>` with `<p:contextMenu>` using primefaces 3.5 on Mojarra 2.2.1.

The ContextMenu Code :

```
<p:contextMenu for="actionnairesDT">  
     <p:menuitem value="View" update="displayActionnaires" icon="ui-icon-search"                    oncomplete="actDialog.show()"/>  
      <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="actionnairesDT" icon="ui-icon-close" />  
</p:contextMenu>
```

the problem is that the dialog box is displayed empty.

I tried to show my object in the setter `setSelecedActionnaire()`, it displays nothing
not even `null`.

```
public void setSelectedActionnaire(Actionnaires selectedActionnaire) {
        System.out.println(selectedActionnaire);
        this.selectedActionnaire = selectedActionnaire;
    }
```

`<p:dataTable>` and `<p:dialog>` code is below. thank you in advance for your help !

```
<p:dataTable id="actionnairesDT"   paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             pageLinks="10" paginator="true" rows="20" value="#{actionnairesBean.actionnairesList()}"  var="actionnaires"
                             rowKey="#{actionnaires.nomAct}"  selection="#{actionnairesBean.selectedActionnaire}"  selectionMode="single"
                             >
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="actionnairesDT" oncomplete="actDialog.show()" />  
                    <p:column  sortBy="#{actionnaires.actionnairesPK.codeAct}" headerText="N°">
                        #{actionnaires.actionnairesPK.codeAct}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Nom" sortBy="#{actionnaires.nomAct}">
                        #{actionnaires.nomAct}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        #{actionnaires.quatiteAct}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Sicav">
                        #{actionnaires.actionnairesPK.codeSicav}
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:dialog header="Détail Actionnaire" widgetVar="actDialog" resizable="false"  
                          showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" id="actDialog" closable="true" modal="true">  

                    <h:panelGrid id="displayActionnaires" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  
                        <h:outputText value="Nom Actionnaire"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{actionnairesBean.selectedActionnaire.nomAct}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Quantité"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{actionnairesBean.selectedActionnaire.quatiteAct}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Sicav"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{actionnairesBean.selectedActionnaire.sicavs.libelleSicav}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I found the solution

I add `<p:ajax>` to the `<p:dataTable>`:

```
<p:ajax event="contextMenu"/>
```